# Adding a ViewController to Appdelegate

Tags: uiviewcontroller

I am trying to add a View Controller to the Appdelegate Class. My code goes this way..

```
[self.view addsubView:viewcontroller.view];
```

But unfortunately i am not able to view the controller view. Please suggest if i am going wrong somewhere.Thanks for ur time.

The method in AppdidFinishLaunching is:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    // [self.window addSubview:videoController.view];
    self.window.rootViewController = videoController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    
    return YES;
}
```

and in the Load view of ViewController i have written as

```
UIButton *playMovie = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
playMovie.frame = CGRectMake(70,30,100,50);
[playMovie setTitle:@"Play Movie" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[playMovie addTarget:self action:@selector(playMovie:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:playMovie];
```

The problem here is i am not able to view the button and the view.Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under no circumstances should you ever add a view controller's view *manually* to the interface like this. The app delegate is not, itself, a view controller; so `viewcontroller` is not its child. So the view is not yours to add. Use view controllers correctly: a view controller is either your app window's `rootViewController`, or it is some other view controller's child - and in either case, its view is placed into the interface for you automatically.

If this view is intended to be the root view of the app, then do what the Xcode 4.2 project templates do (e.g. the Single View Application): instantiate the view controller and assign it as `self.window.rootViewController`. If not, you must not use a view controller to add it as a subview as you are trying to do; just obtain the view and add it, without the intervening view controller.

It might help you to read my chapter on view controllers: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html

Comment: The description provided above as very useful. Thanks for the info. But still when i try to assign the view controller to the window still i am not able to view the viewcontroller. Please help. I am editing the question with the code. Please let me know if i am going wrong somewhere...

Comment: You are saying `self.window.rootViewController = videoController` but I don't see you assigning `videoController` a value; you are never instantiating your view controller. So everything is nil. You have no view controller and no view, so you end up with a white window.

Comment: Also your `loadView` is written incorrectly. Read the documentation (and the chapter I linked to)! In `loadView` you must create the view and assign it to `self.view`. The place to add things to the view is in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

Try below it works for me,

```
SFRmbrVC *viewController=[[SFRmbrVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SFRmbrVC" bundle:nil];
[self.window.rootViewController addChildViewController:viewController];
viewController.parentController = self.window.rootViewController;
viewController.view.frame = self.window.rootViewController.view.frame;
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:viewController.view];
viewController.view.alpha = 0;
[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self.window.rootViewController];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^
 {
     viewController.view.alpha = 1;
 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

The best steps to work out with this are

1. Create your own delegate and make an instance in the AppDelegate

eg.

```
@protocol MyAppDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)myApplicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
@end
```

2. Make a call's of your delegate in the MyAppdelegate

eg.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [myDelegate myApplicationWillResignActive:application]
}
```

3. Implement it in your viewController class (ViewController).

4.assign you viewController class instance to myAppdelegate instance in AppDelegate

eg.

```
MyAppDelegate*myDelegate=(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
myDelegate=self; //self=viewController class
```